# XmlDocument: whitespace handling and normalization

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, system.xml

I have a bunch of questions related to whitespace handling with [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please see the numbered comments in the example below.

1. Shouldn't all whitespace be significant in mixed mode? Why the space between the `a` tags is not significant?
2. While I understand that the actual whitespace element is still an `XmlWhitespace`, how do I normalize these spaces into `XmlSignificantWhitespace` nodes? `Normalize()` doesn't work.
3. Is my only option to do it manually?

Here's my test  case:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // 1. Shouldn't all whitespace be significant in mixed mode? Why the space between the a tags is not significant?
    var doc = new XmlDocument
    {
        InnerXml = "<root>test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>",
    };
    PrintDoc(doc);

    // 2.a. While I understand that the actual whitespace element is still XmlWhitespace, how do I normalize these spaces into XmlSignificantWhitespaces?
    doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAll();
    doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");
    var fragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
    fragment.InnerXml = "test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a>";
    doc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(fragment);
    PrintDoc(doc);

    // 2.b. Normalize doesn't work
    doc.Normalize();
    PrintDoc(doc);

    // 3.a. Manual normalization does work, is there a better way?
    doc.DocumentElement.RemoveAllAttributes();
    var whitespaces = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
        .OfType<XmlWhitespace>()
        .ToList();
    foreach (var whitespace in whitespaces)
    {
        var significant = doc.CreateSignificantWhitespace(whitespace.Value);
        doc.DocumentElement.ReplaceChild(significant, whitespace);
    }
    PrintDoc(doc);

    // 3.b. Reading from string also works
    doc.InnerXml = "<root xml:space=\"preserve\">test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>";
    PrintDoc(doc);
}

private static void PrintDoc(XmlDocument doc)
{
    var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();
    var whitespace = nodes.OfType<XmlWhitespace>().Count();
    var significantWhitespace = nodes.OfType<XmlSignificantWhitespace>().Count();

    Console.WriteLine($"Xml: {doc.InnerXml}\nwhitespace: {whitespace}\nsignificant whitespace: {significantWhitespace}\n");
}
```

The output is following:

```
Xml: <root>test1 <a>test2</a><a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 0
significant whitespace: 0

Xml: <root xml:space="preserve">test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 1
significant whitespace: 0

Xml: <root xml:space="preserve">test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 1
significant whitespace: 0

Xml: <root>test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 0
significant whitespace: 1

Xml: <root xml:space="preserve">test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 0
significant whitespace: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own [`XmlNodeReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.aspx) seems to work, although it is not the "cleanest" solution.

Consider the current implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,abfd2c93a6a62592):

```
public virtual XmlNodeType MoveToContent() {
    do {
        switch (this.NodeType) {
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                MoveToElement();
                goto case XmlNodeType.Element;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
            case XmlNodeType.EndEntity:
                return this.NodeType;
        }
    } while (Read());
    return this.NodeType;
}
```

To get mark [`SignificantWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlSignificantWhitespace.aspx) as content, you may return the `NodeType` when it is `XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace`.

Here's the complete implementation of my own `WhitespaceXmlNodeReader`:

```
internal class WhitespaceXmlNodeReader : XmlNodeReader
{
    public WhitespaceXmlNodeReader(XmlNode node)
        : base(node)
    {
    }

    public override XmlNodeType MoveToContent()
    {
        do
        {
            switch (NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                    MoveToElement();
                    goto case XmlNodeType.Element;
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                case XmlNodeType.EndEntity:
                // This was added:
                case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                    return NodeType;
            }
        } while (Read());
        return NodeType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft documentation is unclear and at least partly inaccurate. Although the Microsoft documentation for the [XmlSignificantWhitespace Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlsignificantwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says that *"white space between markup in a mixed content node"* **is** "significant whitespace," the actual XmlDocument loading and parsing behavior is not consistent with that. Related documentation is [PreserveWhitespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) and [White Space and Significant White Space Handling when Loading the DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab0dyby0(v=vs.110).aspx), but these don't provide enough specific detail.

Empirically, as you've demonstrated with your test cases and with my own testing, the behavior is as follows:

- Whitespace is preserved when `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true` upon load and within an `xml:space="preserve"` scope. However, for the former, it is preserved in `Whitespace` nodes rather than `SignificantWhitespace` nodes.
- If `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false`, then whitespace between elements in a mixed content node is **discarded**, *contrary* to the [XmlSignificantWhitespace Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlsignificantwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation.
- Whitespace is *only* turned into `SignfiicantWhitespace` nodes within an `xml:space="preserve"` scope.  In this case, it is *always* preserved as `SignificantWhitespace`, regardless of the `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace` setting.

In short, the only way to parse whitespace directly into `SignificantWhitespace` nodes is within an `xml:space="preserve"` scope. One way that might work for you is to wrap your XML content in a new outer element with `xml:space="preserve"` scope.  I don't know why your `CreateDocumentFragment()` test did not work, but here's a bit of code that does work:

```
// 4. Loading the XML within an xml:space="preserve" element works
doc.InnerXml = "<root xml:space=\"preserve\"></root>";
doc.FirstChild.InnerXml = "test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a>";
PrintDoc(doc);
```

This results in:

```
Xml: <root xml:space="preserve">test1 <a>test2</a> <a>test3</a></root>
whitespace: 0
significant whitespace: 1
```

Comment: Yes, I came to same conclusion: settings `xml:space="preserve"` and working with strings seems to work properly. I ended up writing my own `XmlNodeReader`, which overrides [`MoveToContent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,abfd2c93a6a62592) and returns `NodeType` if it is `XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace`